# Related objects in activity feed

Tags: getstream-io

I'm building an activity feed application, where a user can like/comments on each activity feed. I went through GetStream.io documentation and looks like I'll have to send the activity with object ids.

```
{  
   id:"ef696c12-69ab-11e4-8080-80003644b625",
   actor:"User:1",
   object:"Comment:12",
   started_at:"2014-11-11T15:06:16+01:00",
   target:"Feed:100",
   time:"2014-11-11T14:06:30.494",
   verb:"add"
}
```

1. `User:1` and `Feed:12` are the objects in my application database? Does it mean that, while retrieving activities, I'll have to hit my database to retrieve the complete feeds?
2. Say the `Feed:12` had few likes and comments earlier from other users. How do I get the complete set of likes/comments on user timeline feed?
3. What if I want to customize the view, say I want to show all users (image, name, the profile like etc) along with comment with timestamp similar to FB? Do I need to send these attributes as additional parameters for each feed?

[image: One level nested comments on each feed activity like FB]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you fetch a feed from Stream and we give you back these references like `user:1` or `comment:12`, we expect that you'd "enrich" those details from your database.

Typically what our users do is track the name of the model (eg, `user`) and the user_id (eg, `1`). When you get the feed and put it into a hash map, you'll iterate over the activities, pull out all of the `actor` attributes, and do a single lookup like `select * from user where id in (1,3,5,6,9,12)` so that you're only hitting your database one time for all user objects or all comment objects or whatever. Then, replace those activities in your hash map so now you'd have `actor: <object for User 9>` and any other attributes you'd need for your UI presentment.

Then do the same for other references you pass in the activity, and so on.

Things we DON'T recommend are putting in string references for things that could change on your side. For example, if you had `actor: "user:ian"` instead of my user_id, if I ever change my username later then things probably wouldn't work properly on your side.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I was looking a paid subscription of the high-end plan with long-term engagement, but I had to wait for more than a month to get this answer. So I decided to build stream on my own, as it is scary to keep waiting for help from their support for such a long time.